# Parsing JsArray into case class without doing it verbosely by referencing the Json keys

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a Json object stored in Mongo like below. It is 'flat', i.e. no nested elements:

```
{
   "key1" : "val1",
   "key2" : "val2",
    ....
   "keyn" : "valn"

}
```

I have fetched it as a JsArray. I also have a case class:

```
case class IndividualProduct(key1: String, key2: String, ... , key_n: String) {}
```

In total the Json will have over 40 key/value pairs. Is there a neat way to parse the JsArray into the case class without verbosely referencing the keys?

thanks in advance - Future[Thanks]

Comment: Wait, as JsArray? Since that's not an array, it should fail. Just fetch it as JsObject instead.

Comment: my apologies for not being clearer. The Json is as represented above, but I have managed to get it as a JsArray from using the ReactiveMongo plugin.

Comment: Then change to JsObject, what's the problem? Maybe you should post that part too, because currently it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, so if I have a JsObject then what do I do to read the values out of it?

Comment: Then you refer to my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val reader = Json.reads[IndividualProduct]
val ip = Json.fromJson[IndividualProduct](fetchedJsObj)
```

Comment: thanks, is the fetchedJsObj the JsArray I have? And does this reader then create the case class with all the fields?

Comment: That's the JsObject that you should have. `Json.reads` is a macro that creates a reader from your case class. For more info refer to the official docs, they explain all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a `JsArray`, but rather a `Map[String, String]`.
So if you have a json like the one you showed, here's what can work:

```
val json = getYourJsonFromDB()
val kv = json.as[Map[String, String]]
```

Now you'll be able to do something like this:

```
val valueForKey13 = kv.get("key13") //returns an Option[String]
```

Hope this helps